# If, if else, else doesn't work in cypress

Tags: conditional-statements, cypress

I have the following code, but block with else if doesn't work,
how can I change this code, to make the if else block work?

```
cy.get('#cards-list').then((list) => {
    const valueFormList = list.find(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`)
    const nextArrow = list.find(`li.pagination-next`)
    if (valueFormList.length > 0 && nextArrow.length > 0){
        cy.get(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`).as('card')
    } else if (valueFormList.length < 0 && nextArrow.length > 0) {
        cy.get('li.pagination-next').click()
        cy.wait(200)
        cy.findCardOnFacebook(nameForSite)
    } else {
        cy.get('h4.learning-opportunities-title').should('contain', 'Learning')
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: code in 'else if' block doesn't work, cypress just skip this condition and iterate with code in block if and else

Comment: What are you testing with your conditional statement?

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of the condition `valueFormList.length < 0`. The length can never be less than 0. Either it can be zero or more than zero.

```js
cy.get('#cards-list').then((list) => {
  const valueFormList = list.find(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`)
  const nextArrow = list.find(`li.pagination-next`)

  if (valueFormList.length == 0 && nextArrow.length > 0) {
    cy.get('li.pagination-next').click()
    cy.wait(200)
    cy.findCardOnFacebook(nameForSite)
  } else if (valueFormList.length > 0 && nextArrow.length > 0) {
    cy.get(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`).as('card')
  } else {
    cy.get('h4.learning-opportunities-title').should('contain', 'Learning')
  }
})
```

Comment: cy.get('#cards-list').then((list) => {
        const valueFormList = list.find(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`)
        const nextArrow = list.find('.pagination-next')
        if (valueFormList.length === 1 && nextArrow.length === 1){
            cy.get(`a:contains('${nameForSite}')`).as('card')
        } else if (valueFormList.length === 0 && nextArrow.length === 1) {
            cy.get('li.pagination-next').click()
            cy.findCardOnFacebook(nameForSite)
        } else {
            cy.get('h4.learning-opportunities-title').should('contain', 'Learning ')
        }
    })

Comment: I changed my code to this but the problem is the same after fail in the first block, second block just skipped

Comment: Can you log `cy.log(valueFormList.length)` and `cy.log(nextArrow.length)` before if-else if you are getting the length correctly or not. Also I have interchanged if and else-if. Now it first checks for length 0 and then length more than 0

Comment: thank you a lot, I recognize that nextArrow.length is always 0 as I select it from div with class '#cards-list' but it`s from another block